# Laptop Display Flickering

Tags: laptop, display, graphics, refresh-rate

It's a brand new laptop, it wasn't flickering before, was just fine. Now it flickers on darker colors such as the windows 8 start menu or a game.

I noticed that this happens exclusively on windows. The BIOS screen seems fine, booting also seems fine, tested with ubuntu, also seems fine, however it flickers on windows. There's only two possible refresh rates, 60hz and 40hz, at 40hz it looks terrible.

Can I force other refresh rates to test?

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try re installing the os?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a hardware problem, I'd try reinstalling your graphics driver. If you don't know what kind of video card you have, try using [HWinfo](http://www.hwinfo.com/).